# Seeking guide for project.

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, fundamental-groups, knot-invariants

I have to submit a project within 2 months for 4th semester(M.Sc). I wish to do it on knot theory, although I know little about it. My plan is to make it an introduction to the subject and to introduce Jone's Polynomial, Conway's Polynomial, Knot group and some examples to show what they exactly do.
Can anyone suggest what material should I cover?(Readers are familiar with Homotopy, but not isotopy). In case you do not get it, I want suggestion on what the content should be or may be an outline.
Thaks in advance..

Comment: A couple of good books to look at are Rolfsen's book "Knots and Links" and Lickorish's book "An Introduction to Knot Theory."

Comment: The "Knot Book" by Colin Adams is my favourite. You should definitely have a look at it if you can find it in the univ. library.

Comment: see if you find the following link useful  http://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/shape-of-nature.html  it is nice video course